# Parsing a list of objects in javascript via index

Tags: javascript

```
 var Filtered_Region = imageCollection.filterBounds(geometry);

var Filtered_Meta_Reg = Filtered_Region.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 20)

var Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg = Filtered_Meta_Reg.filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-12-31')

print(Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg.size())

var Filtered_Free_image = Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg.first();
```

Using this piece of code in javascript i have a list(??) of  class imageCollection objects which are filtered down to 30 using some methods.What i would like to do now is access these elements one by one.

I found that using .first() gives me the first element of this list(please correct me if the type produced is not a list) but i can't access the rest.

What i would like to do is via index use something like `Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg[2],Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg[3]` and access the 2nd and third element.How could this be done?

Comment: You might want to provide more context for what the `imageCollection` is.  By Google search, I'm assuming you are using Google Earth Engine.  Did you [read the docs?](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_iterating)

Comment: Have you tried `Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg[0]`, or `Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg.length`?
Perhaps: `Filtered_Date_Meta_Reg.first().next()`?
@dwmorrin is correct: read documentation.  Also, add tags to the question (where you've put `javascript`), such as `google earth` - if that's the case.